# android async task executing api's repeteadly

Tags: android-asynctask, urlconnection

I am using Android Async Task function to execute an api using urlconnection. this api in turn sends emails to selected users.Now the issue  is I am getting spammed by these emails at first I thought of it as an server side issue or my script but I created a new api and used it on IOS version of my application and everything works fine.But when I execute it on android I start getting spams,so I think the Issue lies in my android programming.

```
public class submitparse extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String> {

    String Url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        URL phonelink;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            phonelink = new URL(params[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) phonelink
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isw);
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalresult = buffer.toString();

            return finalresult;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //If you want further info on failure...
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I am using this command to call it..

```
  submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                String link =  "";
                new submitparse().execute(link);

        }
    });
```

On getting result I start another activity,where link is a string containing url.

Comment: show us some code, otherwise we can't help You

Comment: @Axxxon, I added the code please review...

Comment: AsyncTaks looks ok, can you post code of Your Activities?

Comment: my activity contains a simple onclick listener for the button that's it...

Comment: try to remove `urlConnection.connect();` after `urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) phonelink
                    .openConnection();`

Comment: the code seems to be working now even without the urlconnection.connect() method, but can't really say wheather it would stop executing the url or not when app is killed.I will post if it happens again.

Comment: Ok I kept the modified app running for a while and in background after that still same I am having same issues

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care, you can also use just a new Thread. That should fit your needs and works fine. As far as I read, you don't need to use an AsyncTask and therefore IMO a normal Thread would be better.

```
// Runnable uiThreadRunnable = new Runnable.....
Handler handler = new Handler(); // import android.os.Handler
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do your stuff
        // use 'handler.post(uiThreadRunnable);' to if you NEED to run something on main thread
    }
};

Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
```

Comment: I am using asynctask for executing my api's, hence can't do it on a main thread. Api's running on 3rd party servers for which I am establishing a urlconnection which cannot be executed on UI thread since it's an Async process.

Comment: Yes and that code is going to create a new thread. And if you need to call something of the main thread, you can use the handler.